# Network Flow Graph all possible path

Tags: graph, network-flow

How to find all the possible paths from source(S) to sink(S) in a directed graph?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for solving homework problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is homework, so I'm not going to give a full answer, but I will say that consulting most, if not all, introductory graph theory textbooks will give you an answer. Think about how to find the # of paths between two vertices that are 1 hop long, then 2 hops, 3 hops, etc.